# Sorting binary files : Scala

Tags: java, scala

My requirement is to be able to perform sorting for large files. I have two binary files, one containing the data to be sorted(data.bin) and the other with the index (index.bin). The index represents the start of every row. Each row can contain multiple columns of different dataTypes.

What would be the best way to sort this binary file using the index file and the main requirement is not to copy the data into memory. I want to do this in Scala.

Any help or suggestions or guidance to similar links will be extremely helpful.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: What's the key for your sorting? The entire row, or just a subset of the columns? (but basically, you want to be looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)

Comment: Thanks for the answer(I will go through the link). I would want to sort/order based on ascending or descending. and the algorithm should cater to both single or multi column ordering.

Comment: The reason why I asked about keys is because if the keys and index fit in memory you can just sort those, then write out a new in-order index file